# Why was there no output on HDMI, now there is only output on HDMI?

Tags: nvidia, fedora, display, monitor, hdmi

So the problem is as following:

I have installed Fedora 34 on my Lenovo IdeaPad Gaming 3 (15ARH05). It has an AMD Ryzen 7 4800H as CPU and a nVidia GeForce GTX 1650 Ti Mobile as GPU.

Everything worked fine until I connected my monitor via HDMI cable. The monitor didn't just stay black (backlight was still on) it turned into standby mode. In my opinion there wasn't even electricity on the HDMI port.

I installed nVidia drivers with this commands:

```
dnf config-manager --add-repo=https://negativo17.org/repos/fedora-nvidia.repo
dnf install nvidia-driver-libs nvidia-driver nvidia-settings nvidia-driver-cuda cuda-devel cuda
```

When I boot now I only have video output on the monitor but not on the laptops display. When I try to boot without the monitor connected, process gets stuck at the lenovo logo. When I plug the HDMI cable back in, the laptop display turns black and the login screen appears on the monitor.

`xrandr` does not recognise the display, only the monitor. On run level 3, without the monitor pluged in it says `Can't open screen`.

As X configuration I used the one generated by `nvidia-settings`.

At this point I have no clue anymore and I am completely out of ideas. I hope you can help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying very hard, here now my solution.

Sadly I had to reinstall Fedora as not even a rollback to the nouveau driver worked. Luckily I had no files on the laptop yet. I then installed the drivers from the rpmfusion repo and they are working.

Unfortunately updating those drivers raised the problem again. But a day later there was a kernel update and it got fixed.

So for the future I have the following insights:

- check packages before updating; DO NOT run `sudo dnf update -y`, better run it without `-y`
- remove the HDMI cable before updating anything related to nVidia
- if the problem happens again, hope a kernel update can fix it

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your display server; Try to switch to `Wayland` or `xorg`:

https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/quick-docs/configuring-xorg-as-default-gnome-session/

2. Have you tried boot with `nomodeset` var ?
   I had simmilar problem with laptop display with Intel UHD 620 after kernel update (fedora 33 → 34).
   Laptop screen was not working but second display was.

[How to set `nomodeset` in GRUB](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38780/how-do-i-set-nomodeset-after-ive-already-installed-ubuntu)

About drivers - if problem is related to drivers in fedora 34 you can use [nvidia auto installer](https://ask.fedoraproject.org/t/nvidia-auto-installer-for-fedora-now-works-with-fedora-34/13765)
or rpmfusion

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I had to solve it in another way. I'm posting my solution soon.